# Resort Columns by matching two different lists

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data frame with the following column names:

```
 [1] "416362" "417510" "402634" "406503" "417510" "402634" "402634" "402634" "402634" "402634" "406801" "416631" "407508" "413513" "406801" "416362" "416631" "406603" "407508" "416631" "406603" "406531" "402634" "402634" "402634"
[26] "406503" "413513" "416631" "416631" "406531"
```

Notice that the numbers are jumbled and that there **are** duplicates

I want to reorganize the columns so that they follow this order:

```
[1] "402634" "406503" "406531" "406603" "406801" "407508" "413513" "416362" "416631" "417510"
```

So I want all the column numbers that have "402634" in the jumbled matrix. Then all the column numbers that have "406503" in the jumbled matrix, in a vector, say "x".

I then want to go `df[,x]` to reorganize my data frame `df`.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say the column names are duplicates, are the contents of the duplicated columns the same as?

Comment: @John Hi, no, the contents of the duplicated columns are not the same. In the real data set, its actually 416362_Something1, 416362_Something2.. etc. However I need all the 416362 together and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `order` command on the column names:

```
currentNames = c("416362","417510","402634","406503","417510","402634","402634","402634","402634","402634",
                 "406801","416631","407508","413513","406801","416362","416631","406603","407508","416631",
                 "406603","406531","402634","402634","402634","406503","413513","416631","416631","406531")
df = data.frame(matrix(nrow=3,ncol=length(currentNames)))
colnames(df) = currentNames
df[1:nrow(df),1:ncol(df)] = runif(nrow(df)*ncol(df))
df = df[,order(colnames(df),decreasing=F)]
```